# I want to use enhanced for loop, take input from user and find the element in the array, Why is this program not running accordingly?

Tags: java, foreach

```
public class control {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

        int num[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        char choice;

        System.out.println("Enter your number in the array: ");
        choice = (char) System.in.read();
        for(int x: num) {
            if(x==choice)
            {
                System.out.println("Found");
                break;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are comparing `char` and `int`!

Comment: i think maybe because your comparing the char value to an int,

Comment: While comparing `char` and `int` char returns its position in [Unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/) so char `'1'` is equal to `49` integer.

Answer (score 4):

`if(x==choice)` compares x with choice, where choice is character.
Read int from input like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice = in.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not how to get user input. Instead use a Scanner object.

e.g.,

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
char c = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);

// or
int i = scanner.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

No one mentioned this before, but this:

```
for(int x: num) {
    if(x==choice)
    {
        System.out.println("Found");
        break;
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

look suspicoius, since even if the element is in the array, in will print `Not found` several times, consider changing to:

```
boolean found = false;
for(int x: num) {
    if(x==choice)
    {
        System.out.println("Found");
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!found) {
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach a `Scanner` to properly receive input from the user. In addition, it is best practice to compare like types (`int` to `int`, `double` to `double`, etc) so if someone else looks at the code, they can understand what is going on more clearly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class control {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // <-- add this line
        int num[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int choice = input.nextInt(); //<-- this is the code you should use instead
        for(int x: num){
            if(x==choice)
            {
                System.out.println("Found");
                break;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, your code is currently set to print out "not found" every time it goes through each index when `choice != num[x]`. I'm not sure if that is the intended operation or not, so I will leave that code alone (I believe another answer has that problem resolved in their answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] num = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
boolean found = false;

System.out.print("Enter number to search: ");
// BufferedReader
int numSearch = Integer.parseInt(dataIn.readLine());

    // Check if the number is found
    // if (True) "Found", set found=true then break the search
    // if (false) found remain false
    for(int x: num){
        if(x==numSearch){
        System.out.println("Found");
        found = true;
        break;
        }
    }
    // Condition. if found = false, "Not Found"
    // if found = true this code ignored
    if(!found){
        System.out.println("Not Found");
    }
```